# iPhone OS Utility App - Flipside View and Main View communication

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview

I am currently working on an iPhone 2.1 application. I am new to Objective C, coming from a Java background.

My application has as a base the Utility Application template available in Xcode with the iPhone SDK. Currently I have some controls, such as an `UISlider` and text box, in the `FlipsideView`. The `UISlider` already has a method which is being called when the value changes, using targets and selectors. However, I would also like to be able to read, from the `MainView`, the current (or last) value of the `UISlider` and `textbox`.

Keep in mind I am new to development on a Mac, and would appreciate any guidance as to where I should look up such information, be it through the use of delegates or perhaps I am missing something obvious in the structure of the template.

UPDATE:
I am taking a look at the structure and have some more details: The `UISlider` is being created in `FlipsideView.m`. I noticed that the Done button is created from `RootViewController.m` and probably I should move the `UISlider` code over there. I may incorrectly be using the `View` to keep code that would be more appropiate in a Controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ultimately you should be updating some underlying object with the values from the controller.  In general, the slider belongs in the view layer - it's a display element. The action that adjusting the slider produces, however, is a component of the controller and it should fire back into your model to update a value.  I highly recommend drawing boxes on a sheet of paper and trying to produce a clean a separation as possible for your application's layers - doing so in this case would produce two views for each "side" of the utility which would, via a controller, relate to a model.  Then, the act of moving the slider would "instantly" update the model on the back.  The Cocoa Fundamental video on the iPhone developer site demonstrates this to great effect.

Comment: Appreciated. Being my first iPhone app, I didn't plan it out and whatever worked was left in. I have to refactor and take into account your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in exactly the same situation: first iphone app, new to mac programming, creating a utility, sliders on the flipside.

By following the example and the free tutorial here (http://www.bestechvideos.com/2008/11/13/writing-iphone-app-free-episode) I determined that the sliders and other controls should be declared on the flipsideviewcontroller. (Which leave the view pretty empty - I guess the use of the Nib resource file for the UI leaves  the ...View.m class pretty much redundant?)

Wisequark's answer is a bit to general to help me though. 
In terms of specifics:
 - I can't find that video is there a link?
 - Could we see some code showing the Controller-Model code?
 - How do I persist the values set on the slider without having to build UI to go in the system settings?

(BTW is an Answer the right place to add to the question?)